# How to remove all images from a galleria gallery

Tags: jquery, galleria

I'm building a dynamic gallery with galleria. The idea is that you'd click on a product category and the associated photos are loaded into the gallery.  Clicking a category would first remove all the images currently sitting in the gallery and then load the ones.  I can successfully load new photos in dynamically (below), but I can't figure out how to get rid of all the current ones first.

```
$("#category1").click(function(){
    var category1photos = [
       { image: 'images/products/photo1.jpg' },
       { image: 'images/products/photo2.jpg' }
    ];
    Galleria.get(0).push(category1photos);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a particular reason why you don't change the datasource and rerun the galleria?

[Galleria datasource](http://galleria.io/docs/options/dataSource/)

Then you can easily change the images:

```
var data = [
    { image: "/path/to/myimage1.jpg" },
    { image: "/path/to/myimage2.jpg" },
];

var gallery = this; 
gallery.load(data);
```

Data being any source (JSON, data-attribute, etc)

Comment: Very elegant solution. You don't have to deal with adding/removing data, just telling which dataSource to reference.  Thanks!

Comment: You know what, I may have accepted this answer too soon. Now I'm getting this error:
`Fatal error: Could not extract a stage height from the CSS. Traced height: 0px`

Comment: using .load instead of .run fixes this issue. Edited above.

Answer (score 0):

Check this from the docs:

http://galleria.io/docs/api/methods/#manipulation

```
$("#category1").click(function(){
    // This will remove all the photo from Galleria array: 
    Galleria.get(0).splice( 0, Galleria.get(0).length );

    var category1photos = [
       { image: 'images/products/photo1.jpg' },
       { image: 'images/products/photo2.jpg' }
    ];
    Galleria.get(0).push(category1photos);
});
```

Comment: This isn't quite right. It's clearing the whole gallery, but adding the old ones back.